# time data does not match format. python

Tags: python

I have a date like this:

```
2022-12-29 11:47:07.444185+00:00
```

and I'm trying to format it. I tried this but I'm having an error:

```
utc = datetime.strptime(str(list(Rawdata.objects.filter(
                            id=r).values_list('created_at', flat=True))[0]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')


time data '2022-12-29 11:47:07.444185+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'
```

Comment: there is no space between your microseconds and the timezone

Comment: why don't you just convert it to datetime object using datetime. Then you can do anything with it. What is your final goal? if you want to output it in specific format, you use strftime.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'
```

into

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

More info on formats https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime